# Output manipulation for stderr

Tags: awk, pipe

I have a sets of given hosts. Some of them are linux, other Windows.
Linux systems follow the "sys0123" nomenclature
Windows the "wsys0123" one

With fping, how can I have the stdrr to re-ping the same hosts adding "w" to check which hosts are really linux and which are windows?

I was trying

```
fping -suf /path/to/host_list | awk '{print $0"w"}'; fping -suf /path/to/host_list
```

and

```
fping -suf /path/to/host_list 2> /path/to/host_list awk '{print $0"w"}'; fping -suf /path/to/host_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fping -suf /path/to/host_list 2> >(awk '{print $0"w"}' > /path/to/host_list); fping -suf /path/to/host_list
```

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: Thank you
At the moment the command is printing the "w" at the end and appening all the letters of the alphabet not sure why

I'll see what I can do and potentially posts a reply